# IIS 7.5 connect to a web site using IIS Manager using the current user credentials

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-7.5, delegation

I am trying to use IIS Manager to connect to a site or an application but would like to pass through or use the current authenticated user's credentials. There is only a username and password option when connecting through IIS Manager in this manner.  Is it possible to specify current user credentials somehow?  Our users do not have known passwords since we use smartcard authentication/client certificates mapped to our Windows domain accounts for everything.

Additional information:

- I have the Management Service up and running.
- I can use msdeploy to make a call to the service from the command
  line and recycle an app pool using NTFS (current user credential)
  authentication.
- I can connect to IIS Manager with a local test account
  (userid/pwd) that I do have the password for but this is not
  acceptable solution
- I am trying to connect at the site/app level because the users are
  not administrators on the server.  We are using IIS delegation.